# How to let unauthorised access to a form on one page via token in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, token

I'm building a contacts management application in rails and I need to add in a feature that pretty much goes like this. Each contact which has an email address can be emailed a link to a special form online where the contact can manage their own details so basically if I'm logged in as an administrator I can edit contact ID 12 at the link

```
contacts/12/edit
```

I would want the contact to be able to click on a link - something like the above link except with maybe a secret token i.e

```
contacts/12/edit?auth_token=some-really-jumbled-hash
```

So the contact can click on the link and change the details without having to log into the application. Is there a gem that does this because I'm not sure how I would set up the token part here?

Any ideas?